# Having trouble running the django extensions command reset_db programatically

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-extensions

Basically I am writing a script to reset a django webapp completely. In this script, I want to reset the database, and there is a command to do it from django extensions. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to run it programatically. It works fine when I run it via command line, but it just won't execute when I try programatically.

I have tried using os.system and subprocess.

I have also tried using management.call_command('reset_db'), but it keeps saying that there isn't a command called reset_db. I have checked to make sure the django_extensions is in my installed apps, so I have no idea why that isn't working.

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Thank you!

Also I am using python3, the most recent version of django I believe, and it is a MYSQL server that I am trying to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I can't know without seeing your way of invocation directly, but my guess is the script's not running in the virtualenv. Here are some debug notes:

`./manage.py --help | grep reset_db`: Does this output anything?

`./manage.py shell_plus`

Then try:

- `from django.core.management import call_command`
- `call_command('reset_db', '--help')`

Anything then?

Also within `./manage.py shell_plus`, try `import django_extensions`

Outside of the shell, try this: `pip show django`, `pip django-extensions`.

If it doesn't show those (e.g. `WARNING: Package(s) not found: django-extension`) and you think they're already installed, try this:

`which python`, `which pip`. Are you using `venv`, `virtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper,` pipenv`or`poetry`?

Try `env | grep VIRT`, do you see a `VIRTUAL_ENV`? If not you may need to make one.

When you run the script, you need to have your environmental variables set so you hook in to your site packages. In `poetry` we can do `poetry run ./manage.py ourscript` or `poetry run ./ourscript.py` without needing to be sourced. But we can also easily drop into virtualenv via `poetry shell`.

If you created an environment like `virtualenv -ppython3.8 .venv`, you can either do:

`source .venv/bin/activate`, `./myscript.py`, rr you can try `.venv/bin/python ./myscript.py`